# How to set random seed on tensorflow slim models?

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering how can I set the random seed for building a graph with the [tensorflow slim classifier models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim). I understand I should use `tf.set_random_seed(seed)`. However it is not clear where to add it, because the tf graph is not explicitly declared before calling the `slim.learning.train`.

I.e. there's no

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
```

to put it under